# ::after applies after text inside the tag

Tags: html, css

I want to place dots after the span tag (from one label to another, pointing), but styling appears inside the tag after text. How to make ::after appear exactly after the `<span>` tag?

[image: it's not right, should be outside the span]

```css
.param-name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
}
.param-value {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 52%;
}
.param-value-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.param-name-inner {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  background: inherit;

}
.param-name-inner::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  margin: .85em 0 0;
  content: '';
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAABCAAAAAA+i0toAAAAAnRSTlMA/1uRIrUAAAAMSURBVHheY7j1/z8ABY8C2UtBe8oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<dl class="product-full-params">
  <dt class="param-name">
    <span class="param-name-inner">param</span>
    </dt>
  <dd class="param-value">
    <span class="param-value-inner">value</span>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: pls remove in left:0 in .param-name-inner::after class

Comment: what do you want plz briefly in your question...

Comment: @paragparmmar does not work

Comment: @Sumitpatel I added screenshot with description

Answer (score 0):

I think this CSS will work:

```
.param-name-inner::after {
    height: 1px;
    content: '';
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAABCAAAAAA+i0toAAAAAnRSTlMA/1uRIrUAAAAMSURBVHheY7j1/z8ABY8C2UtBe8oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 0 0 repeat-x;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It almost perfect. The only thing left is to make it appear at the same line with "param" label. Now it appears under this label like a border, it should be on a same level. Have any ideas?